# Apache beam WordCount running error in windows

Tags: maven, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Trying to run [WordCount](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-java/) example of Apache Beam (version 2.0.0) by first running

```
$ mvn archetype:generate \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.beam \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=beam-sdks-java-maven-archetypes-examples \
  -DarchetypeVersion=2.0.0 \
  -DgroupId=org.example \
  -DartifactId=word-count-beam \
  -Dversion="0.1" \
  -Dpackage=org.apache.beam.examples \
  -DinteractiveMode=false
```

then running

```
$ mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount -Dexec.args="--inputFile=pom.xml --output=counts" -Pdirect-runner
```

and getting the following error

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) on project word-count-beam: An exception occured while executing the
>    Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: U
>   nable to find registrar for d -> [Help 1]

However, if I run the same project downloaded and built in Mar 2017 (Beam v0.6.0), everything works fine. I just wonder what update of the Beam release causes this error.

Comment: Is the Error Message cut off? Id there more after "U nable to find registrar for d ->"?

Comment: not much more in any meaningful way. here is more: `[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception `

Comment: I am also running into this problem on Windows. Is it still not fixed?

Answer (score 2):

This error happens due to *TextIO#from("path_to_file")* method doesn't support Windows file system paths.
For example the following code throws *IllegalStateException*:

```
TextIO.read().from("d:\\file.txt") // also "file:\\D:\\file.txt" throw exc
```

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find registrar for d

I hope that Apache Beam team will fix it in near future...

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to indicate you are trying to access a file with invalid scheme.
It comes from here: [FileSystems.java](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileSystems.java)

It may be an issue with your OS.

Can you provide information about your OS and dev environment?

EDIT:
Since you're using Windows as you say and as MeetJoeBlack explains - my first assumption was probably correct.

I suggest you try to run the code via Docker using this [Maven Docker Image](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/maven/)

You can read the howto in there - If you need more help just ping me.

Comment: @srfmk,  my OS is windows 7 64bit.