# Apache Beam - Word Count Example not working

Tags: java, apache-beam

I'm trying to make my own DataFlow runner for Google Cloud.
So first I'm trying to do this locally on my computer.
I tried with [this](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-java/) but when I try to run WordCount I get:

```
C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Test-Beam-3\word-count-beam>mvn compile exec:ja
va -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount -Dexec.args="--inputFile=
pom.xml --output=counts" -Pdirect-runner
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building word-count-beam 0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ word-count
-beam ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Test
-Beam-3\word-count-beam\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) @ word-count-be
am ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. b
uild is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 21 source files to C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Test-Beam-3
\word-count-beam\target\classes
[INFO] /C:/Users/XXX/Documents/Test-Beam-3/word-count-beam/src/main/ja
va/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game/utils/WriteToText.java: C:\Users\aalfe
rezaroca\Documents\Test-Beam-3\word-count-beam\src\main\java\org\apache\beam\exa
mples\complete\game\utils\WriteToText.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] /C:/Users/XXX/Documents/Test-Beam-3/word-count-beam/src/main/ja
va/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game/utils/WriteToText.java: Recompile with
 -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) @ word-count-beam ---
Nov 07, 2017 10:25:17 AM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSource getEstimatedSize
Bytes
INFO: Filepattern pom.xml matched 1 files with total size 14039
Nov 07, 2017 10:25:17 AM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSource expandFilePatter
n
INFO: Matched 1 files for pattern pom.xml
Nov 07, 2017 10:25:17 AM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSource split
INFO: Splitting filepattern pom.xml into bundles of size 3509 took 11 ms and pro
duced 1 files and 4 bundles
Nov 07, 2017 10:25:20 AM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles$WriteShardedBundles p
rocessElement
INFO: Opening writer for write operation TextWriteOperation{tempDirectory=C:\Use
rs\XXX\Documents\Test-Beam-3\word-count-beam\.temp-beam-2017-11-311_16
-25-17-1\, windowedWrites=false}
Nov 07, 2017 10:25:20 AM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles$WriteShardedBundles p
rocessElement
INFO: Opening writer for write operation TextWriteOperation{tempDirectory=C:\Use
rs\XXX\Documents\Test-Beam-3\word-count-beam\.temp-beam-2017-11-311_16
-25-17-1\, windowedWrites=false}
Nov 07, 2017 10:25:20 AM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles$WriteShardedBundles p
rocessElement
INFO: Opening writer for write operation TextWriteOperation{tempDirectory=C:\Use
rs\XXX\Documents\Test-Beam-3\word-count-beam\.temp-beam-2017-11-311_16
-25-17-1\, windowedWrites=false}
Nov 07, 2017 10:25:20 AM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles$WriteShardedBundles p
rocessElement
INFO: Opening writer for write operation TextWriteOperation{tempDirectory=C:\Use
rs\XXX\Documents\Test-Beam-3\word-coun[t-beam\.temp-beam-2017-11-311_1
6-25-17-1\, windowedWrites=false}
WARNING]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.jav
a:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessor
Impl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: java.lang.Il
legalStateException: Unable to find registrar for c
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner$DirectPipelineResult.waitUnti
lFinish (DirectRunner.java:331)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner$DirectPipelineResult.waitUnti
lFinish (DirectRunner.java:301)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run (DirectRunner.java:200)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run (DirectRunner.java:63)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run (Pipeline.java:297)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run (Pipeline.java:283)
    at org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount.main (WordCount.java:185)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.jav
a:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessor
Impl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find registrar for c
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.getFileSystemInternal (FileSystems.jav
a:447)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.match (FileSystems.java:111)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.matchResources (FileSystems.java:174)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.delete (FileSystems.java:321)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSink$Writer.cleanup (FileBasedSink.java:9
05)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles$WriteShardedBundles.processElement (Wri
teFiles.java:438)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.965 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-07T10:25:21-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 36M/647M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (d
efault-cli) on project word-count-beam: An exception occured while executing the
 Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: U
nable to find registrar for c -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception

C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Test-Beam-3\word-count-beam>
```

I tried changing the source of the data from

> gs://apache-beam-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt

to

> C:\The Hunger Games.txt

But nothing. I thought at first it was some issue in the firewall/proxy/network related.
The crash happens on WordCount.java line 184:

```
p.run().waitUntilFinish();
```

I'm surprised this is not working out of the box, because this is supposed to be an example.

Any hints?
Anyone had this issue?

EDIT:

I found [someone said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44147535/apache-beam-wordcount-running-error-in-windows?rq=1) that this is an issue on Windows OS related to the path.
I use Google Cloud Storage (gs) but seems that the code is using some local paths, making this crash. This was some time ago, so I refuse to believe that this issue is still not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused: you say that your input comes from `gs://apache-beam-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt`, but your invocation shows that you're running the program with `-Dexec.args="--inputFile=pom.xml --output=counts"`, and indeed according to its logging output it is reading your `pom.xml` file and counting words in it. Where are you specifying the `kinglear.txt` path?

That said, it should have at least successfully counted words in the `pom.xml`. I think this Windows compatibility issue has been fixed at HEAD - see respective JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2298.

Comment: If I change the gs route with a local route, the output is the same. The file is where the route says.
pom.xml is not the file where you count words from:
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html

Comment: Yes, mvn itself reads pom.xml, but you are also invoking mvn exec with -Dexec.args="--inputFile=pom.xml..", which means you're asking mvn to pass the parameter "--inputFile=pom.xml" to your program, so your program reads the pom.xml file and counts words in it. If you want your program to count words in gs://apache-beam-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt, you need to pass --inputFile=gs://apache-beam-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt.

Comment: I suspect that you've been changing the *default* value of the --inputFile parameter in your .java code - but this is the default value, and it is overridden by whatever you specify on the command line. You can also just not specify --inputFile on the command line, if you would like the default value to take effect.

Comment: Thats correct. its taking that file as input for WordCount.
But still, there is an issue with windows paths, which makes it crash.
I tried the same in Unbuntu and Mac OS, both work out of the box.

Comment: I see. In that case, it matches that JIRA which has already been fixed for the next release.

Answer (score 0):

Can we store the output in CloudSql. If yes, please provide the steps/process

FYI:
I'm able to store the output in cloud storage as per this 
link https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-maven

```
mvn -Pdataflow-runner compile exec:java \
      -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount \
      -Dexec.args="--project=<project_id> \
      --stagingLocation=gs://<bucket>/staging/ \
      --output=gs://<bucket>/output \
      --runner=DataflowRunner"
```